# Conditional static class method access from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have static classes `A`,`B` and `C` like

```
public static class A
{
    public static bool SampleMethod()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public static class B
{
    public static bool SampleMethod()
    {
        ...
    }
}


public static class C
{
    public static bool DoStuff(Enum dataType)
    {
        Type targetClass = null;
        switch (dataType)
        {
            case DataType.1:
                targetClass = typeof(A);
                break;
            case DataType.2:
                targetClass = typeof(B);
                break;
        }

        return targetClass.SampleMethod();
    }
}
```

Im trying to set variable `targetClass` with name of the class. The method im trying to access in class `A` and `B` is with same name. However im getting an error like

> Type doesnot contain definition for 'SampleMethod'

Comment: That is only possible via reflection.  You should use instances and interfaces instead.

Comment: `typeof` returns you the type of the symbol (a `Type` instance). You need to use reflection to look up the right static method against the type and invoke it.

Comment: If the methods and classes don´t need to be static they could implement a common interface the defines `SampleMethod`. In this case you won´t need reflection at all.

Comment: Make `DoStuff` generic, let `A` and `B`  implement the same interface and make a generic constraint on this interface. Then you don't need this

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You don't need generics for that.

Comment: @SLaks: you don't need but it's cleaner imo, you also don't need the enum for this purpose.

Comment: @SLaks - instead of "only" saying you ``don't need it`` you could provide the alternative.

Comment: @Slaks : I just gave an example i have more values coming through the enum.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The whole point of even having a method like that is so that the caller doesn't need to be aware of all of the implementing classes/methods.  If you're going to have the caller specify the type at compile time, there's no need for this method to even exist, the caller can just call `SampleMethod` on that class directly.  So if the callers know which type to use statically, and are expected to be aware of the implementing classes, then there's no reason for `C` to exist *at all*, let alone for it to be generic or for any interfaces to be used.

Comment: Have you tried `targetClass.GetMethod("SampleMethod").Invoke(null,null);` ? (Not *recommending* this, I suggest you go for some of the above suggestions.)

Comment: @RandRandom [Slacks *did* provide an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310658/conditional-static-class-method-access-from-another-class#comment81571809_47310658).

Comment: @RandRandom: Just pass (singleton) instances of classes implementing an interface.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you dont just write ``case DataType.1: return A.SampleMethod();`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other comments said, the type returned from typeof operator is Type, not A or B, so you cannot invoke SampleMethod.

There are several ways to achieve this. Simplest is to use Func to store the method:

```
public static class C
{
    public static bool DoStuff(DataType dataType)
    {
        Func<bool> method = null;

        switch (dataType)
        {
            case DataType.A:
                method = A.SampleMethod;
                break;
            case DataType.B:
                method = B.SampleMethod;
                break;
        }

        return method();
    }
}
```

The other way is to let A, B implement a common interface

Comment: _"so you cannot invoke SampleMethod"_ - Yes, you can! If you really really want to...

Comment: @Fildor of course we can use reflection to invoke method. I was referring to the original code by the author

Comment: I know, I was being nitpicky. Couldn't resist.

Comment: Still dont really get why this should be preferable, instead of just simply ``return A.SampleMethod();``, why keep a reference of that method and call it outside of the switch instead of just simply returning the value in the first place ?!?

Comment: @RandRandom Single point of return? - If one wanted to argue against your suggestion ... which I don't really.

Comment: @RandRandom: maybe OP wants to do other stuff before he returns the `bool`. Of course he could do that normally also before the `switch`. Or this is just a theoretical question because OP wondered.

Comment: @RandRandom yeah you are right that in this case, this doesn't help much. I don't know the reason the author wanted to do this way, so just offer an approach. If the actual problem is just like this, I'm going to call A.SampleMethod() also

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this line `Type targetClass = null;`, targetClass is of type `Type`. A `Type` instance is an object itself, and is therefor not of type `A` or `B`. This means when you set `targetClass` to the value `typeof(A)`, you're not creating an instance of `A` (even if `A` wasn't static you wouldn't), and instead you're setting `targetObject` to a value of type `Type`. This value is an object with meta information about the static class `A`.

What you're trying to do can be acchieved in a couple of ways.

The easiest way I can imagine is using a dictionary that indexes on an enum and stores values of type `Action<bool>` like this:

```
public static class C
{
        private static Dictionary<TypeEnum, Func<bool> dic = new Dictionary<TypeEnum, Func<bool>() {
             { DataType.1, A.SampleMethod },
             { DataType.2, B.SampleMethod }
        }
        public static bool DoStuff(Enum dataType)
        {    
           return dic[dataType].Invoke();
        }
}
```

This approach is limited because it only allows for methods with return type `bool`. There are similar ways to this though that allow for a more generic approach.

Comment: It's a `Func<bool>` not `Action<bool>`

Comment: Hey you're right, I sometimes get the return type vs parameter signature mixed up